# Using Firebase auth as provider in custom backend

Tags: oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, backend, openid-connect, directus

Is there a way to add firebase auth as provider to my custom backend? For my custom backend I am using [directus](https://directus.io/). Directus offers to add auth providers that supports oAuth 2.0 and openID Connect ([docs](https://docs.directus.io/configuration/config-options/#oauth-2-0-and-openid)). But I do not know if firebase auth can be used as an oAuth provider, I did not find about it in the firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/where-to-start?hl=en).

I am using flutter for the frontend part

Answer (score 3):

Firebase does not expose OAuth tokens for its user, so you won't be able to use that integration directly. If you're allowing your users to sign in to Firebase with a social provider (Google, Facebook, etc), you can also pass that token to directus, instead of (or in addition to) signing in to Firebase with it.

Otherwise you **can** take the ID token that Firebase creates for the user, and [verify that in your backend code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens). You won't be using directus' sign-in functionality in that case though.

I also recommend reading: [Demystifying Firebase Auth Tokens](https://medium.com/@jwngr/demystifying-firebase-auth-tokens-e0c533ed330c) for an explanation of Firebase's token types.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I forgot to mention that we want end-user to authenticate and not elevated users like admins. Directus admin panel is pretty good (and the reason why we use it to change things quickly) and we use their authentication solution. Nevertheless I will read through your provided articles and docs and hopefully find the ingredients. 